# Simple search query with prepared statement and explode php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a search query for flight schedules but this query doesnt seem to work. I have a form the executes a query to bring out the flight schedules for airlines when a user search. But for trail, i am using just the location of departure and arriving location. But my current search query doesn't bring out any result even if its in the database. Below are my codes

**mainsearch.php**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

if(isset($_POST['deptfrom']) && isset($_POST['arrat']) && isset($_POST['deptdate']) && isset($_POST['retdate']) && isset($_POST['adults']) && isset($_POST['children']) && isset($_POST['infants']) && isset($_POST['ticket']))
{
$deptfrom = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'deptfrom', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$arrat = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'arrat', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$deptdate = htmlspecialchars($_POST['deptdate']);
$sword = explode(" ", $deptfrom);
$ssword = explode(" ", $arrat);
$retdate = htmlspecialchars($_POST['retdate']);
$adults = htmlspecialchars($_POST['adults']);
$children = htmlspecialchars($_POST['children']);
$infants = htmlspecialchars($_POST['infants']);
$ticket = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ticket', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(empty($deptfrom) || empty($arrat) || empty($deptdate) || empty($retdate) || empty($adults) || empty($ticket))
{
    echo "fill";
    exit();
}
else 
{
    foreach($sword as $dat)
    {
        foreach($ssword as $aat)
        {
            $condition .= " location LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($dat)."%' AND destination LIKE '%".SQLite3::escapeString($aat)."%' AND ";
        }
    }
    $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE " .$condition;
    $sql = $db->prepare($query);

    $result = $sql->execute();

    while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $airline = $row['airline'];

        echo $airline;
    }    
}
}
?>
```

This query doesn't seem to bring out any error or answers. What could be the issue with it? Thanks very much.

Comment: Try echoing your query and see if it works directly in your database. Additionally, you're not actually checking for any database errors.

Comment: @aynber It `echo` directly sir

Comment: @aynber i tried to count the amount of results and it shows zero even if its in the database

Comment: Show your echoed query here so we can see the generated query. If you run that exact query in your database, do you get any results?

Comment: after the row `$query = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE " .$condition;` add the following: `echo $query;` Then copy the query you will get to the db directly and see if you get results

Answer (score 0):

For getting better result you should check errors. if you use mysqli then use `$con->error` by the connection object.

If you use PDO then use

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```